# How should the Trilogy and Stack Exchange be cited in external works?

Tags: discussion, citation

Beside what is outlined in the [Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) page, what are some potential citation formats that could be used? Think along the lines of how you would cite a question/answer in a book, blog posting, paper, etc that you are writing. **Not for re-use of the contents, but *to* the contents**.

I feel that a good format would conform in spirit to other commonly used formats such as IEEE/ACM, APA, etc. This way it would be easier to convert from your proposed style to any of the previous, should strict bibliography and reference rules apply to you work.

I've posted my suggestion below.

#### Edit:

Please note that the purpose of the citations are not for the **reproduction** of content, as described on the Attribution page, but **citations *to* the content**.

Comment: I would use whatever the "standard" formats describe for citing an internet article, listing the poster as authors.

Comment: Jeff's comments in the podcast about the meta users being a little nasty are just turning out to be accurate. I'm guessing that the community sees a lot less value in this topic than I do.

Comment: @I'm really.. Sorry to have wasted your screen real estate, please proceed to the next question, which you possess less dislike for.

Comment: @Dana the Sane: Too bad; this is the newest question and I've already read the others.

Comment: @Dana: If you feel people are nasty, it is likely because you asked something stupid.

Comment: @Rich, I'm not complaining about the response, just remarking that it was negative. If you feel it's a stupid question, you're welcome to that opinion.

Comment: @Dana: You certainly look like you are crying to me.

Comment: @RichB: There's something to be said about tactfulness and general respect for human beings when responding to a dumb question that is well-formed, grammatically tolerable, and at least shows *some* thought was put into it, **regardless** of how dumb the question is. Unfortunately, whatever it is that can be said... cannot be said by you.

Comment: @snicker: I have no reason to sugar coat my response to this person.

Comment: @Rich B: I think we're all a tad curious as to what reason you have to respond *at all*, if you think so poorly of this question.

Comment: @Jonik, I've reworded that part.

Comment: @Quack: I could ask the same of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Book** — however you want to attribute them, as long as they adhere to the attribute rules (URL to question, author's name, URL to author's profile, contextually establish that the source is Stack Overflow and not you)
- **Blog post** — link to the question. (Congratulations, you're using the Web!)
- **Paper** — generally papers have their own styles for attribution when citing sources, so use that style instead of trying to make your own.
- **Something else** — just make sure you use the right attribution and make it clear that the content isn't yours. This isn't rocket science, it's copyright law.

Comment: One more thing: in a book/paper, note the date at which you accessed the online resource (i.e. webpage). Unlike dead trees, online content is subject to change without notice.

Answer (score -3):

```
<ASKER>, <ANSWERER1>, <ANSWERER2>, <...>. <QUESTION TITLE>, <QUESTION ID>, 
    <URL>, <DATE RETRIEVED>.
```

The `<ANSWERER>` fields should probably stick to the top ~3 answers, otherwise we could default to an *et al*.

Comment: See this post: `Dana the Sane, I'm really awesome. Really., RSolberg, Rich B, "How should the Trilogy and Stack Exchange be cited in external works?", 28433, 2009-11-03T13:37:11 AST` There isn't even a URL in this style, and it doesn't even say it's from Stack Overflow. There's not nearly enough information here to find the original work. This format is utter failure at satisfying even a poor set of attribution rules.

Comment: You're right, I intended to include the URL. I've fixed it.

Comment: Now you're missing the fact that you're supposed to link to the author's profile, too, according to Atwood's attribution rules. Having multiple authors confuses this. If you reference them, you'd probably have to link to every one of them. It's better to just reference the answer that contains the details, and list only the author of that answer. If you linked to a forum post, would you attribute it to everyone who participated in the thread, or just the author whose content you're focusing on? In this case, it's usually only the accepted answer that matters.

Comment: @Dana: Did you even bother to read the blog post before posting this?

Comment: If I thought I had the complete answer, than I wouldn't have asked the question. I figured I'd provide my own answer to give others an better idea what I was thinking (perhaps unsuccessfully (or impossible)).

Comment: @Rich, yes, several times. It specifies what should be included. The purpose of the question is to identify some specific ways how it should be included.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want a format in the first place. What is the benefit of having one?

Comment: @dana: But your 'standard' includes none of the necessary attribution. Did you not understand what Jeff was saying?

Comment: I will update my question to explain a bit better, let me think on it for a few minutes.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding is that what I'm asking isn't the same thing as what is on the Attribution page. This isn't for reproducing content, it's for referencing it from somewhere else.

Comment: +1 This is my problem, [too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110006/academic-citations-and-attribution-for-so-se-posts-and-impact-of-cc-by-sa-lice).  Multiple authors/contributors makes it challenging.