# About citing posts on Stack Exchange in scientific literature

Tags: discussion, licensing, citation

Thinking [about the BibTeX template SE uses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267998/what-should-an-bibtex-entry-for-a-stack-exchange-post-look-like) (which yields just awful results when used with LaTeX) I had some questions. I recently commented them on the [legacy post on attribution on SE](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/):

> The need of attribution is clear and not up to discussion. I wonder about the need for linking author profiles.
>
> - In the case of creating PDFs, do the URLs have to be readable in prints?
> - Should we not also list all editors, since posts may well be the result of combined efforts?
> - When posting a whole q&a thread, is it really practical to list *all* answerers?

I have not received an answer, so I'm reposting here. I guess it boils down to these two questions which are not separable:

- To whom do we owe credit when referencing questions vs answers vs whole threads?
- What information has to be visible in screen vs print documents?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49760/citing-stack-overflow-discussions

Comment: The first answer here seems to answer this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28441/2915

Comment: I fail to see the value of citing something as flimsy and volatile as Stack Exchange in sci literature. One should also attempt capturing the page in the Web Archive to prevent link rot and content drift.

Comment: @Chenmunka The accepted answer proposes the (broken) current BibTeX. Citing a whole thread would mean citing question and answers independently, which URLs popping up everywhere, and ignores editors. This question asks, what do we really want?

Comment: @DeerHunter You have a point about stuff that may go away. But still, if you get a question or a puzzle piece of your answer from a website, you *have* to cite it.

Comment: @AdamDavis Basically, "do whatever you want while fulfilling the letter of the license". Was that the official response at any time? I note that my specific questions are still open.